# Converting XML To dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am converting this XML:

```
<root>
    <item id="1" level="1" />
    <item id="2" level="1">
        <item id="3" level="2" />
        <item id="4" level="2" >
            <item id="5" level="3">
                <item id="6" level="4" />
            </item>
        </item>
        <item id="7" level=2" />
    </item>
</root>
```

into a dictionary using this:

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(strSerializedoutput);
Dictionary<int, Pair> list = root.Descendants("item").ToDictionary(x => (int)x.Attribute("id"), x =>
{
    var pId = x.Parent.Attribute("id");
    var depthLevel = x.Attribute("level");
    if (pId == null)
    {
        return new { parentID = 0, level = (int)depthLevel };
    }
    else
    {
        return new { parentID = (int)pId, level = (int)depthLevel };
    }
});
```

where pair is:

```
    public class Pair
    {
        int parentID;
        int level;
    }
```

Output I want to be:

```
ID | ParentID  | level
------------------------
1     NULL         1
2     NULL         1
3      2           2
4      2           2
5      4           3
6      5           4
7      2           2
```

but i am getting an error saying

Error   35  Cannot implicitly convert type
 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary int,AnonymousType#1' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary int,ProposalSystem.handlers.main.Pair'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(strSerializedoutput);
Dictionary<int, Pair> list = root.Descendants("item")
                                 .ToDictionary(x => (int) x.Attribute("id"),
                                  x => {
                            var pId = x.Parent.Attribute("id");
                            var depthLevel = x.Attribute("level");
                            return pId == null ? new Pair { parentID = 0, level = (int)depthLevel } :
                            new Pair { parentID = (int)pId, level = (int)depthLevel };
                          });

public class Pair
{
    public int parentID;
    public int level;
}
```

Comment: when i use new Pair, i get the following errors.Error 35 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<int>' because it is not a delegate type and also 
Error 36 'ProposalSystem.handlers.main.Pair.parentID' is inaccessible due to its protection leve

Comment: @PrakashChennupati your `Pair` should have `public` memebers defined

Answer (score 2):

Your dictionary is of type:

```
Dictionary<int, Pair>
```

Yet for the element type, you are not returning `Pair` but this anonymous type:

```
return new { parentID = 0, level = (int)depthLevel };
```